# GRUB not showing up after installing ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

Before question, I'm completely new to linux and ubuntu, so pardon me.

I've installed ubuntu to my ssd, where I've installed my Windows. I've created two partitions while creating ubuntu. Each of them named sda5/sda6, which is for efi partition (because an alert popped up while installing ubuntu)/ext4(for installing ubuntu). After install, I rebooted my computer, and only I see is ubuntu startup screen, neither windows boot manager or GRUB. What should I do?

+I've removed my restore partitions before ubuntu install. Does this will be the cause of my problem?

---

Ok. I've found the problem. It was the problem of windows (which is probably my fault). It didn't have bootmgfw.efi. But thanks for all of your help. Gonna re-install windows and try again to install Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get dual-boot working fine on your laptop, you can check these steps:

**Section - I: Getting Windows OS ready for Dual-boot**

- Login to your `Windows` machine with an Administrative account and right-click on the **Start Menu >> Command Prompt (Admin)** option to open Windows Command Line with elevated privileges
- Once you are in the command prompt, type `diskmgmt.msc` to open "Disk Management Utility". From here, right click on the "C:" partition and select **Shrink Volume** in order to resize the partition
- On "Shrink C:" enter a value to shrink in MB and hit the **Shrink** option to start partition resize

**Note:** Do not forget to create a Bootable USB having Ubuntu loaded into it before you start with the next section.

**Section - II: Installing Ubuntu OS**

- Reboot the machine and instruct the BIOS/UEFI to boot-up from the DVD/USB by pressing a special function key (usually its <kbd>F12</kbd>, <kbd>F10</kbd> or <kbd>F2</kbd> depending on the vendor specifications)
- Once the media boot-up, a new Grub screen should appear on your monitor. From the menu select **Install Ubuntu** and hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to continue

**Note:** After the boot media finishes loading into RAM you will end up with a completely functional `Ubuntu` system running in live mode

- On the "Launcher" hit on the second icon from the top, **Install Ubuntu 18.04**, and the installer utility will start. Choose the language you wish to perform the installation and click on the **Continue** button to proceed further
- Next, leave both options from **Preparing to Install Ubuntu** unchecked and hit on the **Continue** button again
- On the "Installation Type" screen, prefer to choose the **Install Ubuntu alongside Windows Boot Manager** option if you want to automate the process and do not wish to have a personalized partition scheme. In case you want a custom partition layout, check the **Something Else** option and hit on the "Continue" button to proceed further.

**P.S.:** The option "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" should be avoided on dual-boot because is potentially dangerous and will wipe out your disk completely.

- Now, if you go with "Something Else" option, its time to create the partitions manually. I would recommend that you create three partitions, one for **root**,  one for the **Home** and one "Swap" partition.
  To create the first **root** partition, select the free space (the shrinking space from Windows created earlier) and hit on the "+" icon below. On partition settings use the following configurations and hit OK to apply changes:

> Size = at least 20000 MB
>
> Type for the new partition = Primary
>
> Location for the new partition = Beginning
>
> Use as = EXT4 journaling file system
>
> Mount point = /

- Similarly, create the "Home" partition and the "Swap" partition. For "Home" use the following configuration:

> Size = all remaining free space
>
> Type for the new partition = Primary
>
> Location for the new partition = Beginning
>
> Use as = EXT4 journaling file system
>
> Mount point = /home

- When you are finished creating all partitions as per your requirements, hit the **Install Now** button in order to apply the changes to disk and start with the installation process. A pop-up window might appear to inform you about the "Swap" space, but you can ignore the alert by pressing on the "Continue" button
- Next a new pop-up window will ask you if you agree with committing changes to disk. Hit the **Continue** button to write changes to disk and the installation process will now start

Once you are done installing `Ubuntu` OS, proceed with the next section.

**Section - III: Setting Up the GRUB Menu**

- Boot into your `Windows` OS
- Combine the keys <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> together and type **cmd** to open command prompt.
- Type the command: `bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` and hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key

**P.S.** - You do not need to have admin rights on command prompt before you perform the above action.

If you wish to switch between the OS, just reboot the computer and select your preferred OS from the Grub menu.

**Section - IV: Unable to Load into Windows & Booting directly into Ubuntu**

In case you boot directly into `Ubuntu` OS and do not get the GRUB menu, perform the following steps:

- Create a file: `/boot/grub/custom.cfg` by running the command: `sudo -H gedit /boot/grub/custom.cfg` with these contents:

> menuentry "Windows (UEFI)" {
>
> search --set=root --file /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
>
> chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
>
> }

**Note:** Copy and paste the above code into the Gedit window. Save the file and quit Gedit.

- Reboot your system and you should be able to see an entry titled **Windows (UEFI)**
- Select it and the `Windows` OS should boot.

If this doesn't work, please run the **boot info script** (http://bootinfoscript.sourceforge.net/ ) and post the RESULTS.txt that it produces so that we can help you accordingly.

**P.S.** You can also try and use the **GRUB tool**.

Comment: I cant' even access to windows since grub doesn't show up and directly boot to ubuntu. What should I do?

Comment: Hello, @JustSingleUser I have updated my answer. Follow the steps listed in Section - IV and update us.

Comment: @ManuMathur Sorry for the late response. I've done your 4th option, but it didn't work. I'm pasting my pastebin link of bootinfo script:https://pastebin.com/tw2edYRW

Comment: @ManuMathur changed my os to lime with little hope, but didn't work. bootinfo is written at lime

Comment: The Section IV also did not work for me, this is my script result: https://pastebin.com/PGaQgCW6, are the "No boot loader is installed" the reason, why it boots straight into ubuntu? More detailed question: https://superuser.com/q/1525848/1140736

Comment: yes, @FelixB. 
you need to have a proper Boot loader to ensure you get the options to pick your choice of OS while booting the system.

Comment: @ManuMathur I guess I am just reaaaally lucky with my first installation -.-

Comment: Sorry, but didn't understand your comment that well. Kindly explain @FelixB.

Comment: @ManuMathur In the link to the question on the superuser stackexchange I explain in more detail what I did. But apparently updating the grub configuration won't help anyway since there seems to be no boot loader. I have no idea why there is no boot loader and I currently have no idea how to get one.

Comment: @ManuMathur Is this `sudo grub-install /dev/sdX  # Example: sudo grub-install /dev/sda` what I am looking for? Apparently I am not supposed to provide a partition number - does this have the chance to break anything? I mean at least I have "working" ubuntu installation right now... (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing)

Comment: Try disabling the "Fast Startup" option on Windows OS. 

You can do this by going to "Control Panel > Hardware and Sound > Power Options > Choose what the power buttons do > Change settings that are currently unavailable" > Scroll to the bottom of the Window and Un-check "Turn on fast startup (recommended)" box. 

After that shutdown your Windows OS and most likely you will get the boot loader option to pick OS. 

If not, then boot into Windows OS again, and open the Command Prompt with elevated rights (Open as Administrator). Input the following command: powercfg /h off

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104532/discussion-between-felix-b-and-manu-mathur).