# No Boot Loader after Ubuntu Installation (18.04.2 LTS)

Tags: boot, grub2

I've recently purchased a new laptop and i wanted to install Ubuntu, replacing Windows 10.
After setting my BIOS CSM Support to Enabled and Secure Boot to Disabled, i proceeded with my ubuntu setup. 
I selected "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" choice but after a successful installation, when i rebooted my laptop instead of launching GRUB my BIOS appeared telling me there was nothing to boot.

Comment: Check my answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1124684/grub-not-showing-up-after-installing-ubuntu/1124686#1124686

It will help you configure your GRUB also.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply, but my purpose is to erase Windows, which is what i've already did. Problem is that Ubuntu is installed but i can't launch it because GRUB is not appearing on boot and looks not available on my BIOS boot options. When i tried to install Ubuntu again (and i did it already 2 times), it recognizes my previous Ubuntu installation, so it is installed correctly on the disk. I just don't know how to launch it.

Comment: Try these links: 

1. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode 

2. https://askubuntu.com/questions/681422/grub-menu-not-showing-with-dual-boot-uefi-mode-installation

They might help you. 

Awaiting your staus update.

Comment: You installed in the now Legacy/BIOS/CSM boot mode which dates back to mid 1980's. Your system is new UEFI system and you really should install Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI